# Subclipse cannot load default SVN client, even though everything is installed properly

Tags: linux, eclipse, subclipse

I'm having a problem with Subclipse, when trying to do anything like committing, updating or viewing history the first time nothing happens, and the second time I try this error show up:

[image]

All this used to work just fine but suddenly it stopped working. All the required packages are installed:

[image]

The "SVN interface" option in the preferences is empty/greyed out:

[image]

I have another Eclipse installation (Java EE) which has the same packages installed and everything is still working fine there.

I've already tried reinstalling all the SVN packages but to no avail. I'm running Eclipse Kepler on Linux Mint 16 Petra, SVN is version 1.7.9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I figured out that the other Eclipse installation had different (older) versions of the plugins. After updating these, that installation also stopped working. I suspect that my SVN version (1.7.9) is too old. I see 1.8.x has already been released, how can I install that version in my Linux installation? Running apt-get update/upgrade doesn't do it. I've seen some people talking about running dist-upgrade but that has broken things in the past so I'm very reluctant to do so unless absolutely necessary.

EDIT: I managed to install subversion 1.8.10 using [these](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharadchhetri.com%2F2014%2F02%2F05%2Finstall-subversion-1-8-on-ubuntu-using-apt%2F&ei=yJ-aVN22HMbraMiRgKgN&usg=AFQjCNEz-No-7P3hJz2iRT3qYRs8-RE6EA&sig2=aR6M6IJgxxB5Ux1gq8hQmA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d2s) steps, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue my removing SVNKit and installing the "Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter" instead. I tried that before but it did work after I had also updated subversion to 1.8.